# How to draw a small segment for UnFill?

Tags: asymptote

```
settings.outformat="pdf"; 
settings.prc=false;
settings.render=0;

import graph;
import math;

unitsize(1cm);
size(10cm,0);
defaultpen(linewidth(1bp));
//--------------
void pstLabelAB(pair A, pair B, Label L="", pen Labelcolor=currentpen, 
                real dis=1, real d=6, real posLabel=0.5, bool line=true,
                pen fillframe=blue, pen drawframe=green, filltype FillType=NoFill,
                arrowbar arrow=None, arrowbar bar=None, pen sty=currentpen)
{
pair M,N;
M=A+dis/10*dir(degrees(B-A)+90);
N=B+dis/10*dir(degrees(B-A)+90);
path  h = N--M;
real rotate_angle = degrees(dir(h));
 //===================
if (line) {
  draw(h,arrow,bar,p=sty);
  frame f;
  label(f,L,Labelcolor,FillDraw(fillframe,drawframe));
  if (d==0){  add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f,position=relpoint(h,posLabel)+d/10*dir(rotate_angle-90),filltype=FillType);  }
   else { add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f,position=relpoint(h,posLabel)+d/10*dir(rotate_angle-90)); }
  }
else
  {
  frame f;
  label(f,L,Labelcolor,FillDraw(fillframe,drawframe));
  if (d==0){  add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f,position=relpoint(h,posLabel)+d/10*dir(rotate_angle-90),filltype=FillType);  }
    else { add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f,position=relpoint(h,posLabel)+d/10*dir(rotate_angle-90)); }
  }
}
//--------------
pair A=(3,3),B=(-3,-3);
path pathAB=A--B;
dot("A",A,red); dot("B",B,green);
//----
pstLabelAB(A,B,"Hello",dis=0,d=0,fillframe=red,drawframe=pink,FillType=UnFill(0.5),arrow=Arrows(size=5mm),bar=Bars(size=7));
pstLabelAB(A,B,rotate(90)*"Hello",dis=0,d=0,posLabel=.8,fillframe=red,drawframe=pink,FillType=UnFill(0),line=false);
pstLabelAB(A,B,rotate(-90)*"Hello",dis=0,d=0,posLabel=.2,fillframe=red,drawframe=pink,FillType=UnFill(0.01mm),line=false);
```

Question:

How to draw a small segment as image?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related issue was discussed on https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/06dad034/. The problem is that the bounding box of a rotated frame includes the whole area of the rotation and is therefore larger than the box itself. The solution on the linked page was to fill the label with white and print that without UnFill. However, in your example the label is already filled, so that solution does not apply. A related approach is to draw a white box with as size the size of the label plus some margin, and draw the label in there (and do not use UnFill).

The margin is hardcoded as `5pt`, to change the gap distance you should modify this value. Note that only the x direction is affected, you may need to set also the `ymargin` based on the rotation of the label. Furthermore, the pen color should be changed if the background is not white.

Code:

```
box(f,L,xmargin=5pt,ymargin=0,p=white,filltype=Fill);
label(f,L,Labelcolor,FillDraw(fillframe,drawframe));
if (d==0){  
   add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f,position=relpoint(h,posLabel)+d/10*dir(rotate_angle-90),filltype=NoFill);
}
else {
   add(rotate(rotate_angle)*f,position=relpoint(h,posLabel)+d/10*dir(rotate_angle-90));
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: More explanation. Thanks for your answer.